# Googlemail users can't email my email address

Tags: email, mediatemple, gmail

I have a GridServer account at MediaTemple. The address linked up to my MT account is mail@mysite.com.

My non-Google email address could email mail@mysite.com just fine. But when my friend tried to email it from his gmail address, he got the following message:

> From: Mail Delivery Subsystem
>    Date:
>   Thu, Apr 15, 2010 at 12:02 PM Subject:
>   Delivery Status Notification (Failure)
>   To: myfriend@gmail.com
>
> Delivery to the following recipient
>   failed permanently:
>
> ```
> mail@mysite.com
> ```
>
> Technical details of permanent
>   failure: Google tried to deliver your
>   message, but it was rejected by the
>   recipient domain. We recommend
>   contacting the other email provider
>   for further information about the
>   cause of this error. The error that
>   the other server returned was: 550 550
>   relay not permitted (state 14).
>
> ----- Original message -----
>
> MIME-Version: 1.0 Received: by
>   10.231.205.139 with HTTP; Thu, 15 Apr 2010 12:02:26 -0700 (PDT) In-Reply-To:
>   <95AA8B48-FF48-4FF1-8DB2-0EFD5D7F1211@mysite.com>
>   References:
>   <95AA8B48-FF48-4FF1-8DB2-0EFD5D7F1211@mysite.com>
>   Date: Thu, 15 Apr 2010 12:02:26 -0700
>   Received: by 10.231.169.144 with SMTP
>   id z16mr211585iby.25.1271358147047;
>   Thu,
>          15 Apr 2010 12:02:27 -0700 (PDT) Message-ID:
>   
>   Subject: Re: Hi Friend From: My Friend
>    To:
>   "mail@mysite.com" 
>   Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
>   boundary=0016e6d26c5abcb2a704844b22bf
>
> Does this work. Does this work. Does
>   this work?
>
> On Thu, Apr 15, 2010 at 11:30 AM,
>   mail@mysite.com 
>   wrote:
>
> > Hi Friend.
> >
> > Just testing the email address I set up for My Site. Could you please reply
> >     so I can check if it's working OK?
> >
> > Cheers
> >
> > Jack

I thought it was just a fluke, but exactly the same thing happens when I use MY Gmail address that I also have. Can anyone shed some light on the problem?

Jack

Comment: It's not possible to troubleshoot this (other than random flailing) without knowing the actual address that's having trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your domain is rejecting e-mails:

> Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the recipient domain.

Have you tried any other sources for e-mail to see if it's a general problem or if it's just rejecting e-mails from `gmail.com`.

Double check that you've set up the mail part of your GridServer account correctly.

After than, I'd check with MediaTemple to see if they can shed some light on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your pal's configuration is correct and that you can replicate this from other domains, then your mail server is rejecting the mail because it doesn't think it should be responsible for mail at mysite.com.

Check your server configuration.

Check to see if your pal isn't just fat fingering this or if he's trying to use an SMTP he shouldn't be using.