# Email can't be sent to my domain

Tags: domain-name-system, email, mediatemple, gmail

***Edit: My problem is solved (but I can't accept my own answer for another two days)***

Hi Folks,

Basically I have my domain howcode.com bought at DomainMonster.com. I have set it all up to point to MediaTemple nameservers and everything works - mostly - fine. I have registered an email address mail@howcode.com.

The setup is, I presume, working correctly. I can successfully send emails with the account. And I presume I can receive them - but the problem is, nobody can send them to me.

Emailing from a regular, non-Googlemail account appears to work fine but it never arrives in the inbox.

But when you email from a GoogleMail address, an error message is instantly returned saying this:

---

> Delivery to the following recipient
>   failed permanently:
>
> ```
> mail@jkljkl.com
> ```
>
> Technical details of permanent
>   failure:  Google tried to deliver your
>   message, but it was rejected by the
>   recipient domain. We recommend
>   contacting the other email provider
>   for further information about the
>   cause of this error. The error that
>   the other server returned was: 550 550
>   relay not permitted (state 14).
>
> ----- Original message -----
>
> Received: by 10.216.91.12 with SMTP id
>   g12mr3673969wef.77.1271503997091;
>          Sat, 17 Apr 2010 04:33:17 -0700 (PDT) Return-Path:
>    Received:
>   from [192.168.0.3]
>   (client-81-98-94-79.cht-bng-014.adsl.virginmedia.net
>   [81.98.94.79])
>          by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id x1sm29451927wbx.19.2010.04.17.04.33.15
>          (version=TLSv1/SSLv3 cipher=RC4-MD5);
>          Sat, 17 Apr 2010 04:33:16 -0700 (PDT) From: Jack
>   
>   Mime-Version: 1.0 (Apple Message
>   framework v1078) Content-Type:
>   multipart/alternative;
>   boundary=Apple-Mail-7--1008464685
>   Subject: Re: Hi Date: Sat, 17 Apr 2010
>   12:33:14 +0100 In-Reply-To:
>   <273957B1-5AA9-425B-89B1-B0C810094D7A@jkljklj.com>
>   To: Jack
>    References:
>   <273957B1-5AA9-425B-89B1-B0C810094D7A@jkljklj.com>
>   Message-Id:
>   <621C4BC9-DF06-4073-BC0F-7AA1189D6A0D@googlemail.com>
>   X-Mailer: Apple Mail (2.1078)
>
> Does this work? On 17 Apr 2010, at
>   12:32, Jack wrote:
>
> Hi

---

I thought this may be something to do with my MX DNS settings. They are setup like so:

```
MX name: jkljklj.com
TTL: 43200
Type: MX
Data: 10 jkljklj.com.
```

The A-Record for mail.howcode.com is setup like this:

```
Name: jkljklj.com
TTL: 43200
Type: A
Data: 205.186.187.129
```

Is this what's going wrong with the issue?

Thanks very much

Jack

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/132850/googlemail-users-cant-email-my-email-address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mediatemple said:

"Jack,

The problem is that the mail service for howcode.com is disabled in the Enable/Disable Mail control panel."

Hahaha. Ah well.

Comment: yes, that's because someone might provide a better answer. In your case probably not, but in general that's why the restriction is there. For more check out threads on meta.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

Please not than some servers will pelanize or fail your mail due to your rdns failing to resolve correctly.

mail.howcode.com -> 205.186.187.129 -> ekiaiooqmm.c06.mtsvc.net

You may want to change your mail server identity to `ekiaiooqmm.c06.mtsvc.net` or get your ISP to change the rdns entry to `mail.howcode.com`.